# Replacing NumPy array values (finite set of unique values) with a list of new values

Tags: python, numpy

How can I make the following code faster? It takes an hour for a large NumPy array.

```py
    i = 0
    for y in np.unique(y_in):
        y_in[y_in == y] = i
        i += 1
```

e.g. y_in contains any of these six values [0.1, 0.22, 0.27, 0.4, 0.51, 0.92] and I want to replace all 0.1 with 1, 0.22 with 2, etc.

Comment: Can you give an example of the data you are working with and what values you want to replace the unique elements with?

Comment: I think you just need to flatten the array and then assign the values in one sweep like: ```y_in[y_in == np.unique(y_in)] = i```, where ```i``` is the replacing values.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`numpy.unique` already does that:

```
In [1]: import numpy

In [2]: x = numpy.array([5, 3, 5, 5, 6, 8, 3, 6])

In [3]: y, z = numpy.unique(x, return_inverse=True)

In [4]: z
Out[4]: array([1, 0, 1, 1, 2, 3, 0, 2])

In [5]: y
Out[5]: array([3, 5, 6, 8])
```

Here, `z` is the array you're trying to build. It's much faster, and avoids the bug in your code where an index might get updated twice (for example, if all 2s get replaced with 6s, and then all 6s get replaced with 8s).

Answer (score 0):

I think this behaviour can be vectorized like this (assuming `y_in` is 1d):

```py
y_in = np.array([0.1, 0.22, 0.27, 0.4, 0.51, 0.92])
y_in = np.arange(1,y_in.size+1)[np.unique(y_in, return_inverse=True)[1]]
y_in
```

Output:

```py
array([1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6])
```

An example with non-unique values in `y_in`:

```py
y_in = np.array([0.1, 0.22, 0.22, 0.4, 0.4, 0.92, 0.92, 0.92])
y_in = np.arange(1,y_in.size+1)[np.unique(y_in, return_inverse=True)[1]]
y_in
```

Output:

```py
array([1, 2, 2, 3, 3, 4, 4, 4])
```